# Is it possible to get an "inverse" function of a Boolean function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was looking to write an "all-or-nothing" function over an array. One approach is, of course, to leverage `Array.prototype.every` and do something like

```js
function allOrNothing(arr, f, fInv) {
  return arr.every(f) || arr.every(fInv);
}
```

where `f` and `fInv` are indicator functions, and `fInv` is an "inverse" function of `f`. For example, if `f = (x) => x != null`, then `fInv = (x) => x == null`.

This leads me to think: is it possible to get the function `fInv` from `f`?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Are you just looking for `!` (logical 'not')? As in `fInv = x => !f(x)` ?

Comment: It seems that you want to negate the result.

Comment: In your trivial example, fInv is effectively "not f". For arbitrary functions, it depends on what behavior you expect, I suppose. Might work OK for pure functions that simply return boolean.

Comment: @MarkReed Yes! I totally missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function, given a function f as an input, returns its boolean inverse:

`let invert = (f) => (x) => !f(x)`

e.g.

```js
let invert = (f) => (x) => !f(x)

let eq_five = (x) => x == 5
let neq_five = invert(eq_five)

console.log(eq_five(5)) // true
console.log(neq_five(5)) // false
```